# Cross platform Expression Encoder 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I have a very simple use case. I am using expression encoder 4.0 for my application. This application need to run on x86 as well as x64.

Problem: When I run it by making it "architecture independent" we get warnings about target incompatibility.

```
Warning 1   There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference "Microsoft.Expression.Encoder, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of your project.  IDS
```

How can I make these warnings go away.

Answer (score 0):

Expression Encoder exists only as a 32-bit version. (But it still works on a 64-bit OS by using [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64).)

To get rid of the warning you would have to change your project to `32-bit (x86)`, but you should also be save with ignoring it.